# smoothstate injecting wrong head elements into page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, smoothstate.js

### The Issue

[Smoothstate.js](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js#loadurl) keeps the `<head>` of the page that I was just on and injects it back into the home page when I navigate back to `index.html`.

For example: I click a link that takes me to `proj1.html` Then I want to leave that page by clicking the home link which directs back to `index.html`. Page directs back to home but the layout is broken because the home page `<head>` contains the contents from `<head>` of `proj1.html`..Thus making all my styles are broken on the home page.

Smoothstate is caching the `<head>` and I am not sure how to prevent this from happening...

I tried using the cache clearing method they have but no success. `smoothState.clear();`

Here is my JS

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var $page = $('#main'),
      options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 0,
        onStart: {
          duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
          render: function ($container) {
            // Add your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');
            // Restart your animation
            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
          }
        },
        onStart: {
          duration: 0,
          render: function ($container, $newContent) {
            // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
            // Inject the new content
            $container.html($newContent);
          }
        }
      },
      smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The `<head>` loading issue was caused by not adding the appropriate classes to `$page` object.

1. `#main` contains all the content I wanted to fade.
2. `head` is our `<head>` element that contains all styles.
3. `body` entire body of the page.

`var $page = $('#main','head','body')`

```
$(function(){
  'use strict';
  var $page = $('#main','head','body'),
      options = {
        debug: true,
        prefetch: true,
        cacheLength: 1,
        blacklist:'.luxbar-item',
        onStart: {
          duration: 250, // Duration of our animation
          render: function ($container) {
            // Add your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.addClass('is-exiting');
            // Restart your animation
            smoothState.restartCSSAnimations();
          }
        },
        onStart: {
          duration: 0,
          render: function ($container, $newContent) {
            // Remove your CSS animation reversing class
            $container.removeClass('is-exiting');
            // Inject the new content
            $container.html($newContent);
          }
        }
      },
      smoothState = $page.smoothState(options).data('smoothState');
});
```